# Tricky JOIN Question with unexpected results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to run a query for reporting purpose and its behaving in a way that I can't wrap my hand around. If someone can help me with this one at;least I could sleep in peace

Table Data are as below

```
Table1
-------

account_no|consumer_domain_name|system|search_text|status
AB00001   |XY00001             |Linux | Null      |active
AB00002   |XY00002             |Sybase| Null      |partial-active


Table2
------

consumer_domain_name|
XY00001            | 
XY00002            |


Table3
------


custodian_user_id|consumer_domain_name|
user-test1        |XY00001            |
user-test2        |XY00002            |

SELECT * FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 cad ON a.consumer_domain_name = 
cad.consumer_domain_name 
INNER JOIN table3 c ON c.consumer_domain_name = cad.consumer_domain_name 
WHERE 
LOWER(a.status) LIKE "%active%"
OR (LOWER(a.search_text) = LOWER("")
OR LOWER(c.custodian_user_id) = LOWER("")
OR LOWER(a.system) = LOWER(""))
```

So the problem I am having is to arrange conditions in such a way if 2nd condition i.e.

```
LOWER(a.search_text) = LOWER("")
OR LOWER(c.custodian_user_id) = LOWER("")
OR LOWER(a.system) = LOWER("")
```

is true in any of the statement,

```
LOWER(a.search_text) = LOWER("")
OR LOWER(c.custodian_user_id) = LOWER("user-test1")
OR LOWER(a.system) = LOWER("")
```

it should display

```
custodian_user_id|account_no|consumer_domain_name|system|status
user-test1       |AB00001   |XY00001             |Linux |active
```

else

```
custodian_user_id|account_no|consumer_domain_name|system|status
user-test1       |AB00001   |XY00001             |Linux |active
user-test2       |AB00002   |XY00002             |Sybase|partial-active
```

I have a query with multiple joins and multiple conditions on various fields. Conditions can be categorized in 2 main conditions that i want to check.. such as either (a) OR (x or y or z) ... What I really wanted to do is if none of the conditions x,y,z are true then run condition 'a' else run 'x or y or z' ... some how it is always running a even if one of x,y,z is true.... Really appreciate if some one can point me to the right direction. Thanks

Comment: provide a more concrete example with sample data and expect output.

Comment: I can't follow your logic.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to do here.

Comment: From what i see your logic should get implemented in a case statement not in where clause.

Comment: As an aside, are you sure that you're using a case sensitive collation?

Comment: What does `LOWER("")` mean, are you actually comparing against the lowercase of an empty string or is it a placeholder where parameter will always be like 'user-test1'

Comment: it is like a place holder but it could be empty as well

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
WHERE 
  (x = 'value1' OR y = 'value2' OR z = 'value3') OR 
  ((x != 'value1' and y != 'value2' and z != 'value3') and a = 'value4')
```

the explaination of this query is:

- Get results for x = 'value1'
- Get results for y = 'value2'
- Get results for z = 'value3'
- Get results if x is not 'value1' and y is not 'value1' and z is not value1
      **but a is 'value4'**. In other words if none of the x,y,z conditions returns result then process `a = 'value4'`

or

```
WHERE 
  (x = 'value1' OR y = 'value2' OR z = 'value3') OR 
  (NOT (x = 'value1' OR y = 'value2' OR z = 'value3') and a = 'value4')
```

Comment: Sorry.. this doesn't work too... if any of x,y,z are true ... they come up correctly... but if they are all empty ... doesn't come up with the correct result

Comment: i tried with SELECT * FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 cad ON a.consumer_domain_name = 
cad.consumer_domain_name 
INNER JOIN table3 c ON c.consumer_domain_name = cad.consumer_domain_name 
WHERE 
(a.search_text = ""
OR c.custodian_user_id = "" 
OR a.system = "") OR
(a.search_text != ""
AND c.custodian_user_id = "" 
AND a.system = "")
AND a.status LIKE "%active%"

Comment: @PinkNinja this needs to work. can you provide me sample data using https://dbfiddle.uk/ ?

Comment: You have the exact same problem here that you complained about in my answer, both groups of conditions before and after OR will always be checked.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @PinkNinja, maybe there are to many OR conditions and strange dependencies between them, it is hard to say if/how this can be done differently since we don't know the requirements for your report